# get SUM of salesQty base on product id

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
select pt_product_name,
  (select 
     sum(sal_qty)
   from sales_tb as sal
   where pt.pt_productid=sal.sal_pt_productid
   and sal.sal_updated_time>curdate()
  ) as salQty
from product_tb as pt
```

It returns the `sum` of sal_qty for every product, but i want the `sum` based on the different products. 
Can you please point me to the right direction, what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Please use code formatting, and try and produce a data sample with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY pt.pt_productid` to your select statement, to have the `sum()` be applied to product groups.

Also consider using `JOIN` instead of nested selects.

**update**

```
select pt_product_name, 
  (select sum(sal_qty) from sales_tb as sal
    where pt.pt_productid=sal.sal_pt_productid
    and sal.sal_updated_time>curdate()
  ) as salQty
  from product_tb as pt
  group by pt.pt_productid;
```

using **`JOIN`**:

```
select pt_product_name, sum(sal_qty) as salQty
  from product_tb as pt
  left outer join sales_tb sal on (pt.pt_productid = sal.sal_pt_productid 
      and sal.sal_updated_time>curdate())
  group by pt.pt_productid
```

Here is a sample table structure filled with sample values, and the demonstration that the queries work fine:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_db`.`product_tb`;
    CREATE TABLE  `temp_db`.`product_tb` (
        pt_productid int(10) not null auto_increment,
        pt_product_name varchar(20) not null,
        primary key (`pt_productid`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_db`.`sales_tb`;
    CREATE TABLE  `temp_db`.`sales_tb` (
        sal_saleid int(10) not null auto_increment,
        sal_pt_productid int(10) not null references product_tb.pt_productid,
        sal_qty int(10) default 0,
        sal_updated_time timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
        primary key (`sal_saleid`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

adding sample data to the tables:

```
    insert into product_tb(pt_product_name) values 
        ('prod1'), ('prod2'), ('prod3'), ('prod4');
    insert into sales_tb(sal_pt_productid, sal_qty) values 
        (1, 40), (1, 40), (1, 10), (1, 20),
        (2, 4), (2, 4), (2, 4), (2, 4), 
        (3, 1), (3, 1), (3, 1),
        (4, 5), (4, 5);
```

The result of the select statements (both return the same resultset):

```
# pt_product_name, salQty
prod1   110
prod2   16
prod3   3
prod4   10
```

**Note**, that a quantity will only be summed, if it was sold **today or later***! `sal_update_time > curdate();`

If a product does not have any sales for curdate() or later, it won't even appear in the list. This does not mean, that the select is wrong, this means that you didn't specify correctly what your target is.

Comment: please provide any example

Comment: i have three product.but it shows one product and sum(allprdqty)

Comment: Please add an update to your question with your table structures and the current search statement that gives you only one row.

Comment: Also, is the sum right for that product listed? Or is it still returning the whole sum? In the first case move the update time check from the ```JOIN``` to the main ```WHERE``` clause.

Comment: yes the products has to be listed.but sum(allprdqty) shown on first product quantity

Comment: Share your table structure and the updated select statement, that still doesn't fulfill your requirements.

Comment: i am edited my question.please see this.

Comment: Please see my update, and check how your tables are defined. If your problem persist, paste your table structures as well!!!

Comment: @jingly, could you sort it out? If not, please be more specific, if so, either accept an answer, or post your own and accept that, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    pt.pt_product_name,
    sum(sal.sal_qty) as salQty
from
    product_tb as pt
        left join
    sales_tb as sal on pt.pt_productid = sal.sal_pt_productid
where
    sal.sal_updated_time > curdate()
group by pt.pt_productid
```

This queries joins all the products with their respective sale. It then groups all the records for the same product together. The records are then filtered according to the current date. Each one of these groups will contain one record for each sale of a single product. Finally, in the select we sum, for each group, all the sold quantities.

Comment: it gives answer like product name and sum(allprdQty).but i want prdname sum(prdqty)

Comment: The sum(...) is only applied to each group (because of the group by). Each group contains all the sales for a single product. As a result, it will return a row for each product. Each row will contain the product name and how many times that product has been sold.

Comment: again i have the same problem

Comment: i have three product.but it shows one product and sum(allprdqty)

Comment: Because of sal.sal_updated_time > curdate() a product won't appear in the result unless there is at least one sale that satisfies that condition.